# Accesing superclass attribute during subclass construction in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

Is it possible to access superclass's attributes during class construction?
Here's my code:

```
class A:
   x = 1

class B(A):
   x += 1   # <- error
```

The increment line `x += ...` is not valid, because `x` is not defined at this moment. You may suggest doing it in `__init__`, but I need to initialize the values before the constructor and want to minimize the code.

The code `x = A.x + 1` will not work in my case because the `A` is generated in run-time. So the real code for `B` looks like

```
class A:
  x: int

def class_gen(params):
  class SubA(A):
    x = 1
  return SubA

class B(class_gen(some_params)):
  x += 1
```

I've found a weird workaround:
`x = A.__subclasses__()[-1].x + 1` (indeed the last subclass of `A` will be the generated super), but it looks too dirty and unstable.

Another workaround is declaring the a 'stub' class variable:

```
...
_Stub = class_gen(some_params)
class B(_Stub):
  x = _Stub.x + 1
```

but is it also looks urgly. Is there a better way for a perfectionist?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can accomplish it by using `__new__` in the subclass.

```
class A:
    x = 1

class B(A):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.x += 1
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

b = B()
print(b.x)  # 2
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is going to increment every time you create a new `B` instance, which I don't think is desired...

Comment: You are right, I'm not sure why it behaves like that.

Comment: `B.__new__` is called to create instances of `B`, not to create the `B` class itself.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do this. Probably the best is to give your `B` class a metaclass that handles incrementing of the `x` attribute for you:

```
class XIncrementerMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace):
        namespace['x'] = bases[0].x + 1
        return super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace)

class B(class_gen("some_params"), metaclass=XIncrementerMeta):
    pass

print(B.x) # prints 2
```

If you need each `B`-like class to have its own kind of manipulation of the `x` value, you could put it in a classmethod and have an inherited metaclass call it. Or you could even have an `__init_subclass__` method in `A` that calls methods to set the value on its subclasses:

```
class A:
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        cls.set_X()

class SubA(A):
    @classmethod
    def set_X(cls):
        cls.x = 1

class B(SubA):
    @classmethod
    def set_X(cls):
        super().set_X()  # get SubA to set an initial value
        cls.x += 1       # then update it

print(B.x) # prints 2
```

Comment: In my case, the `x` is the property of class `A` by its nature. You may think of it as a **factory**. (I could create a proper factory here, but why would I do this in mighty python?). The value of `x` will be common for all instances and I don't want to consume this amount of memory (there are dozens of B-like classes and dozen of millions of instances). 

I've made some tests: having this property of the class saves 20% of the elapsed time (7->5.5 hours) and 20% of memory consumption (5Gb -> 4 Gb). It matters. After all Python supports this, but I need a better syntax: `super()` for `cls`.

Comment: In real code, `x` is a `map`. So updating it in the constructor makes a lot of duplicated data. The instances cannot share it.

Comment: The code I show updates the value in a metaclass, which only runs once when `B` is created. It doesn't do anything when `B` instances are created, it's put the value in a class attribute, just like you asked for.

Comment: It does put it into the right place, but the update itself is in the wrong place. There will be lots of B-like subclasses with different variations of updating the `x`. I need to declare this inside `B`s. Of cause, there are multiple workarounds (one can pass the delta to the metaclass or `class_gen`), but the readability suffers.